# Como fazer controle de acesso ao scripts com JekyllCMS

Tags: javascript, criptografia

Estou usando o [JekyllCMS](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) para desenvolver um CMS (*Content Management System*), mas como não o conheço muito bem e mesmo depois de ler a documentação, sinto dificuldade de "esconder" alguns dados que uso no *JavaScript*. São dois casos: A `access_key` do [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) e a *key* do [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/). Uso essas duas *keys* no meu código para adquirir *feed* de uma determinada página do Facebook e redirecionar *e-mails* para uma determinada caixa postal. Como posso privar o usuário final do acesso à essas *keys*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, não tem problema você disponibilizar sua APIKey na internet, no Maindrill e no Facebook você terá as opções de víncular sua APIKey a um domínio ou IP, ou seja, aquela APIkey terá uso apenas se as chamadas forem do seu IP permitido.

No Maindrill você terá a opção: **Only Allow The Key To Work From Certain IP Addresses** e você terá como usar mais genéricas, porém, limitadas e poderá usá-las de qualquer lugar com a opção: **Only Allow This Key To Use Certain API Calls**.

A mesma coisa repete-se para o Facebook.. Você poderá ter uma lista de domínios/subdomínios que serão permitidos realizarem essas chamadas.

É importante entender que o conceito de APIKey é diferente do conceito de secret key, espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida.